# Adding control from other thread in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

my question is how can I add dynamic panel with dynamic button and text to windows form from other. I tried the following code but it doesn't display the dynamic panel.

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
            {
                this.showMessageBox.Text = "hello";

                //----------------------------------------------------------
                Panel dynamicPanel = new Panel();
                dynamicPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
                dynamicPanel.Name = "Panel2";
                dynamicPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(529, 353);
                dynamicPanel.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;

                Label kifg = new Label();
                kifg.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                kifg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 100);
                kifg.Text = "TLD NUMBER - " + "kifg";
                kifg.Size = new Size(209, 50);

                Button exitButton = new Button();
                exitButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 300);
                exitButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                exitButton.BackColor = Color.Coral;
                exitButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 45);
                exitButton.TabIndex = 6;
                exitButton.Text = "Exit";
                exitButton.Click += exitButton_Click;

                dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(tldNumber);
                dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(exitButton);

                this.Controls.Add(dynamicPanel);
            }));
```

Comment: Start one by one..generate panel first..working?.add panel first then add controls on them

Comment: I think your sequence for adding controls is wrong. As per @utility told already add panel first.

Comment: Whats on your current form? Are you sure its not being placed behind another control?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Controls.Add(dynamicPanel);
dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(kifg);
dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(exitButton);
```

Comment: no this also doesn't work I have already tried this changing order.

Comment: I think I am making mistake, order doesn't matter but I had not cleared the previous panel due to which new panel was not being displayed

Answer (score 0):

I had made a mistake. I had not cleared the previous panel due to which new panel was not being displayed.

Comment: also you were not using : kfig to add in panel